# How to logout from firebase pre-build login ui

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I'm Using Firebase prebuild UI in my `kotlin` application, 
it is working great to log in, but I can't logout 
I've tried:

```
        logout_button.setOnClickListener {
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()
            LoginManager.getInstance().logOut()
                val loginActivity = Intent(this, LoginActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(loginActivity)
        }
```

which suppose to logout the user and takes him back to the login screen, in the login screen itself I'm adding this check :

```
    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        val user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
        if (user != null) {
            toast(getString(R.string.logged_in))
            val mainActivity = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(mainActivity)
        } else {
            toast(getString(R.string.please_login))
        }

    }
```

And here is the activity result for my `ActivityLogin`:

```
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {


            val response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data)

            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                val user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
                if (user != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.logged_in), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    val mainActivityIntent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(mainActivityIntent)
                }
            } else {
                // Sign in failed. If response is null the user canceled the
                // sign-in flow using the back button. Otherwise check
                // response.getError().getErrorCode() and handle the error.
                // ...
                println("Sign in Failed, Error code: ${response?.error?.errorCode} ")

            }
        }
    }

    companion object {
        const val RC_SIGN_IN = 1
    }
```

Now after logging out I just get back to the `main activity` and being logged in again

**Note**

I'm only using `facebook` login

```
    private val providers = arrayListOf(
        //AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(),
        //AuthUI.IdpConfig.PhoneBuilder().build(),
        //AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build(),
        AuthUI.IdpConfig.FacebookBuilder().build()
       // AuthUI.IdpConfig.TwitterBuilder().build()
    )
```

**UPDATE**

`getting`unresolved reference` error when I try to catch the error :

[image]

Comment: FirebaseAuth.getInstance().addAuthStateListener(firebaseAuth -> {
            if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
                //User Logged out
            }
        });

Comment: Use StateListener to check when User logged out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call this as you want to perform action after sign Out.

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut().then(function() {
      // Sign-out successful.
 val loginActivity = Intent(this, LoginActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(loginActivity)
    }).catch(function(error) {
      // An error happened.
    });
```

Comment: This is not working already, I think its something Java and kotlin function structure.